# D3.js is not displaying on screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I have tried to draw the map of new york in the following way:
But there is nothing displaying. I'm not sure what is wrong

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-scale-chromatic.v1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<svg id="my_dataviz" width="400" height="300"></svg>


<script>

// The svg
var svg = d3.select("svg"),
    width = +svg.attr("width"),
    height = +svg.attr("height");

// Map and projection
var projection = d3.geoNaturalEarth1()
    .scale(width / 1.3 / Math.PI)
    .translate([width / 2, height / 2])

// Load external data and boot
d3.json("newyork.geojson", function(data){

    // Draw the map
    svg.append("g")
        .selectAll("path")
        .data(data.features)
        .enter().append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#69b3a2")
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)
            )
            .style("stroke", "#fff")
})

</script>
```

Link to the json file:
[link](https://data-beta-nyc-files.s3.amazonaws.com/resources/6df127b1-6d04-4bb7-b983-07402a2c3f90/f4129d9aa6dd4281bc98d0f701629b76nyczipcodetabulationareas.geojson?Signature=gApueGr1zXdboqUl2F%2FPYVcYFEs%3D&Expires=1666694928&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAWM5UKMRH2KITC3QA)

I only see a blank canvas and nothing else. Can someone plz help me?

Comment: presumably new york's co-ordinates our outside the range 400 by 300 of your svg canvas.

Comment: @RobertLongson Hi, thank you so much for your reply. How can I fix this?

Comment: figure out where new york is and construct an appropriate viewBox

Comment: @RobertLongson can't i adjust the center and scale to make the map without using view box?

Comment: sure you could do that instead, it amounts to pretty much the same thing.

Comment: var projection2 = d3.geoMercator()
  .center([40.730610, -73.935242])                
  .scale(200)                   
  .translate([ width/2, height/2 ])

Comment: @RobertLongson still its not showing

Comment: @RobertLongson i have put a link to the json file along with the code.

Comment: Your center needs to be longitude then latitude, you have latitude then longotude

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My tooltip is stuck at the bottom in d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74207799/my-tooltip-is-stuck-at-the-bottom-in-d3-js)