# My tooltip is stuck at the bottom in d3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, d3.js

I am trying to recreate a map using the following code in d3.js. It is an interactive map. When I hover over the circles, it should show a tooltip. But the problem is that my tooltip is not moving with the mouse. It is stuck at the bottom of the canvas. I have tried changing the style. I don't know what is wrong with it. Can someone please help me resolve this issue?
I am using d3 version 4.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<!-- Load d3.js and the geo projection plugin -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<style>
.circle:hover{
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}
</style>

<script>

  // Size ?
  var width = 460
  var height = 400
  
  // The svg
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  
  // Map and projection
  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .center([4, 47])                // GPS of location to zoom on
      .scale(1020)                       // This is like the zoom
      .translate([ width/2, height/2 ])
  
  // Create data for circles:
  var markers = [
    {long: 9.083, lat: 42.149, name: "Corsica"}, // corsica
    {long: 7.26, lat: 43.71, name: "Nice"}, // nice
    {long: 2.349, lat: 48.864, name: "Paris"}, // Paris
    {long: -1.397, lat: 43.664, name: "Hossegor"}, // Hossegor
    {long: 3.075, lat: 50.640, name: "Lille"}, // Lille
    {long: -3.83, lat: 58, name: "Morlaix"}, // Morlaix
  ];
  
  // Load external data and boot
  d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson", function(data){
  
      // Filter data
      data.features = data.features.filter( function(d){return d.properties.name=="France"} )
  
      // Draw the map
      svg.append("g")
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(data.features)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#b8b8b8")
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)
            )
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("opacity", .3)
  
      // create a tooltip
      var Tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .style("border", "solid")
        .style("border-width", "2px")
        .style("border-radius", "5px")
        .style("padding", "5px")
  
      // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
      var mouseover = function(d) {
        Tooltip.style("opacity", 1)
      }
      var mousemove = function(d) {
        Tooltip
          .html(d.name + "<br>" + "long: " + d.long + "<br>" + "lat: " + d.lat)
          .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+10) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
      }
      var mouseleave = function(d) {
        Tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
      }
  
      // Add circles:
      svg
        .selectAll("myCircles")
        .data(markers)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d){ return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0] })
          .attr("cy", function(d){ return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1] })
          .attr("r", 14)
          .attr("class", "circle")
          .style("fill", "69b3a2")
          .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .attr("fill-opacity", .4)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
  
  })
  
  </script>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your x,y coordinates for the tooltip were good, you were just missing `position: absolute;` for their styling. I chose to add it to the `<style>` element you had in the snippet below, but you could have done it in JS with `.style()` too.

I also chose to add `position: relative;` to `#my_dataviz` to keep the absolute positioning of the tooltips relative to that container.

```html
<!-- Load d3.js and the geo projection plugin -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<style>
.circle:hover{
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

#my_dataviz {
 position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
}
</style>

<script>

  // Size ?
  var width = 460
  var height = 400
  
  // The svg
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  
  // Map and projection
  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .center([4, 47])                // GPS of location to zoom on
      .scale(1020)                       // This is like the zoom
      .translate([ width/2, height/2 ])
  
  // Create data for circles:
  var markers = [
    {long: 9.083, lat: 42.149, name: "Corsica"}, // corsica
    {long: 7.26, lat: 43.71, name: "Nice"}, // nice
    {long: 2.349, lat: 48.864, name: "Paris"}, // Paris
    {long: -1.397, lat: 43.664, name: "Hossegor"}, // Hossegor
    {long: 3.075, lat: 50.640, name: "Lille"}, // Lille
    {long: -3.83, lat: 58, name: "Morlaix"}, // Morlaix
  ];
  
  // Load external data and boot
  d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson", function(data){
  
      // Filter data
      data.features = data.features.filter( function(d){return d.properties.name=="France"} )
  
      // Draw the map
      svg.append("g")
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(data.features)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#b8b8b8")
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)
            )
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("opacity", .3)
  
      // create a tooltip
      var Tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("opacity", 1)
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .style("border", "solid")
        .style("border-width", "2px")
        .style("border-radius", "5px")
        .style("padding", "5px")
  
      // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
      var mouseover = function(d) {
        Tooltip.style("opacity", 1)
      }
      var mousemove = function(d) {
        Tooltip
          .html(d.name + "<br>" + "long: " + d.long + "<br>" + "lat: " + d.lat)
          .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+10) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
      }
      var mouseleave = function(d) {
        Tooltip.style("opacity", 0)
      }
  
      // Add circles:
      svg
        .selectAll("myCircles")
        .data(markers)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d){ return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0] })
          .attr("cy", function(d){ return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1] })
          .attr("r", 14)
          .attr("class", "circle")
          .style("fill", "69b3a2")
          .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .attr("fill-opacity", .4)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
  
  })
  
  </script>
```

Here is another snippet that hides the tooltip using `display: none;` instead of changing `opacity`. This fixes a bug where one of the circles (for example, Corsica) may no longer receive mouse events because the tooltip is sitting on top of it despite being invisible.

```html
<!-- Load d3.js and the geo projection plugin -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3-geo-projection.v2.min.js"></script>

<!-- Create an element where the map will take place -->
<div id="my_dataviz"></div>

<style>
.circle:hover{
  stroke: black;
  stroke-width: 4px;
}

#my_dataviz {
  position: relative;
}
.tooltip {
  position: absolute;
  display: none;
}
</style>

<script>

  // Size ?
  var width = 460
  var height = 400
  
  // The svg
  var svg = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
  
  // Map and projection
  var projection = d3.geoMercator()
      .center([4, 47])                // GPS of location to zoom on
      .scale(1020)                       // This is like the zoom
      .translate([ width/2, height/2 ])
  
  // Create data for circles:
  var markers = [
    {long: 9.083, lat: 42.149, name: "Corsica"}, // corsica
    {long: 7.26, lat: 43.71, name: "Nice"}, // nice
    {long: 2.349, lat: 48.864, name: "Paris"}, // Paris
    {long: -1.397, lat: 43.664, name: "Hossegor"}, // Hossegor
    {long: 3.075, lat: 50.640, name: "Lille"}, // Lille
    {long: -3.83, lat: 58, name: "Morlaix"}, // Morlaix
  ];
  
  // Load external data and boot
  d3.json("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/holtzy/D3-graph-gallery/master/DATA/world.geojson", function(data){
  
      // Filter data
      data.features = data.features.filter( function(d){return d.properties.name=="France"} )
  
      // Draw the map
      svg.append("g")
          .selectAll("path")
          .data(data.features)
          .enter()
          .append("path")
            .attr("fill", "#b8b8b8")
            .attr("d", d3.geoPath()
                .projection(projection)
            )
          .style("stroke", "black")
          .style("opacity", .3)
  
      // create a tooltip
      var Tooltip = d3.select("#my_dataviz")
        .append("div")
        .attr("class", "tooltip")
        .style("background-color", "white")
        .style("border", "solid")
        .style("border-width", "2px")
        .style("border-radius", "5px")
        .style("padding", "5px")
  
      // Three function that change the tooltip when user hover / move / leave a cell
      var mouseover = function(d) {
        Tooltip.style("display", "block")
      }
      var mousemove = function(d) {
        Tooltip
          .html(d.name + "<br>" + "long: " + d.long + "<br>" + "lat: " + d.lat)
          .style("left", (d3.mouse(this)[0]+10) + "px")
          .style("top", (d3.mouse(this)[1]) + "px")
      }
      var mouseleave = function(d) {
        Tooltip.style("display", "none")
      }
  
      // Add circles:
      svg
        .selectAll("myCircles")
        .data(markers)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
          .attr("cx", function(d){ return projection([d.long, d.lat])[0] })
          .attr("cy", function(d){ return projection([d.long, d.lat])[1] })
          .attr("r", 14)
          .attr("class", "circle")
          .style("fill", "69b3a2")
          .attr("stroke", "#69b3a2")
          .attr("stroke-width", 3)
          .attr("fill-opacity", .4)
        .on("mouseover", mouseover)
        .on("mousemove", mousemove)
        .on("mouseleave", mouseleave)
  
  })
  
  </script>
```